# Using changepage and caption package with a wide figure

Tags: captions, changepage

The following example generates two figures in total, one on a recto and and one on a verso page.

```
%
\documentclass{book}
%
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{font=footnotesize}

\RequirePackage[strict]{changepage} 

%
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=100mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=240pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{mwe}
%

\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-120pt}
    \captionsetup{style=widefigure}
    \includegraphics[height=80pt,width=400pt]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text.}%
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}%
%

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-120pt}
    \captionsetup{style=widefigure}
    \includegraphics[height=80pt,width=400pt]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text.}%
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}%


\end{document}
```

However, the resulting pdf does not properly extent and/or align the figure caption. Adding `width=400`, `calcwidth=400` or either starred version did not help. I am certain that that the `changepage`and `caption` packages played nice at some point using the same LaTeX code. After updating my TeXLive to the newest, i.e. frozen, TeXLive 2019 did most likely cause the change. What (option) am I missing?

[image: output of the first page] [image]

Comment: With version `v3.4a`(2019/10/18) of the `caption` package, I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frk6Y.png

Comment: That is what I want and got until now (my TeXLive full update). But I cannot figure out, which (updated) package changed the behavior. I have "2020/01/03 v1.8h caption3 kernel (AR)" of the caption package.

Comment: I have both MacTeX2019 and MacTeX2020 (pre-release version) on my system. When I compile your code under either system -- both employ `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`, `caption 2020/01/03 v3.4h`, and `caption3 2020/01/03 v1.8h` -- I get the result shown in @leandriis' screenshot.

Comment: I also use MacTeX2019 (fully patched, i.e. empty list in TeX Live Uitlity). It shows `2020/01/03 v3.4h Customizing captions (AR)` and `2020/01/03 v1.8h caption3 kernel (AR)`and my log starts with `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`. To be sure, I emptied `~/Library/temf/tex/latex`and put the testfile in an empty directory. Is there any place, where old packages can hide?

Comment: @Mico: Now, I installed the MacTeX2020 pre-release version. It shows the same result. I also tried as a different user on the same system with the same incorrect result. I am really puzzled. I am on Catalina, if that means anything...

Comment: You can use \hsize=\linewidth, or put the \caption inside a minipage.

Comment: The minipage works. However, is there any possible explanation what changed with updating TeXLive and why @Mico does not have that behavior on the same?! system. I would happily use the minipage solution in my documents, but I am reluctant to patch it in a package (yet).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Can you put the minipage solution in an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, the minipage solution.  I also threw in the `\hsize` solution.

BTW, the reason it takes two runs to work is that adjustpage uses the AUX file to determine the current (even/odd) page layout.

```
\documentclass{book}
%
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{font=footnotesize}

\usepackage{changepage} 
%
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=170mm, paperheight=100mm, left=42pt, top=40pt, textwidth=280pt, marginparsep=20pt, marginparwidth=100pt, textheight=240pt, footskip=40pt]{geometry}
%
\usepackage{mwe}
%

\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-120pt}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{style=widefigure}
    \includegraphics[height=80pt,width=400pt]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text.}%
    \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}%
%

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-120pt}\hsize=\linewidth
    \captionsetup{style=widefigure}
    \includegraphics[height=80pt,width=400pt]{example-image-b}%
    \caption{A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text. A larger rectangle in the main area of the text.}%
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}%

\end{document}
```