# caption of sidenote package's figure* (widefigure) has wrong margin or width in twosided document

Tags: captions, sidenotes, wide-image

In a two sided document, caption of a `figure*` (widefigure) has wrong width and margin in even page.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{sidenotes} %% To typeset the rich content in the margin. It also loads caption package.
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{format=plain,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,textfont=up,labelsep=period}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{fig}}
\caption{(a) The electric field vector of linearly polarised monochromatic light,
travelling along $z$, at a given instant of time. The 
entire pattern moves past any given plane, say $z=0$; so the time
variation would be the same curve read in reverse, with the part at
positive $z$ arriving earlier. The magnetic field B is shown
only at one plane, $z=0$, but is equal to the electric field (in
cgs units!) but along $y$.}
\end{figure*}

xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx 

\marginpar{xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx}


\newpage

\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{fig}}
\caption{(a) The electric field vector of linearly polarised monochromatic light,
travelling along $z$, at a given instant of time. The 
entire pattern moves past any given plane, say $z=0$; so the time
variation would be the same curve read in reverse, with the part at
positive $z$ arriving earlier. The magnetic field B is shown
only at one plane, $z=0$, but is equal to the electric field (in
cgs units!) but along $y$.}
\end{figure*}


xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx 

\marginpar{xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx}



\end{document}
```

**Following result is on odd page.**

[image: On odd page]

**Following result is on an even page.**

[image: On even page]

Answer (score 1):

I reported the issue to Caption package author Axel Sommerfeldt on Gitlab. He has a workaround for the problem and fixed it ([Commit cc7fb506 on Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/commit/cc7fb50644cf708240769fd8d2b40b6e5d4cb57e)) and updated the package hosted in Gitlab. He said the update will be available in CTAN by next week. You can also update your caption package by copying the files from https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/tree/master/tex into the directory where the file `caption.sty` is currently located on your TeX system. To know the location of `caption.sty` use the following command.

```
$ kpsewhich caption.sty
```

Or use any other method (like TexLive manager `tlmgr`) which you know to update the package from CTAN (next week).

As he pointed out the issue is with the use of `adjustwidth` environment from `changepage` package which the `sidenotes` package is using to typeset widefigure. He has a workaround to detect whether the caption is in `adjustwidth` environment and appropriately set the caption code. He also suggests

> As an alternative you could put `\hsize=\linewidth` inside the affected figures as work-around.

The updated `caption` package or the temporary solution of putting `\hsize=\linewidth` inside the affected figures as work-around has an added advantage. After any of these fixes try the following settings for the same example given above and see it yourself.

```
\usepackage{sidenotes} %% To typeset the rich content in the margin. It also loads caption package.
\newlength{\xtramargin}
\setlength{\xtramargin}{\dimexpr \marginparsep +\marginparwidth}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{format=plain,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,textfont=up,labelsep=period,
    margin={0cm,\xtramargin},twoside}
```

For more details on the issue:

- https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/136#note_841021759
- https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/78
- https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/81
- [Using changepage and caption package with a wide figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536412/using-changepage-and-caption-package-with-a-wide-figure)

Comment: `twoside` does not work! Must use `oneside`. Please check my answer.

Comment: It works after updating the `caption` package from Gitlab or as a temporary solution by putting `\hsize=\linewidth` inside the `figure*` environment. It gives the expected result. The expected result is with caption width equal to the textwidth and only the picture extending to the margin. Odd and even pages are taken care appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your code shows the caption aligned with the left edge of the figure and with a width equal to the width of the text, on both odd and even pages.

If you want to enlarge the caption like the `figure*` add this code

```
\newlength{\xtramargin}
\setlength{\xtramargin}{\dimexpr \marginparsep +\marginparwidth}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{format=plain,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,textfont=up,
    labelsep=period, margin={0cm,-\xtramargin},oneside }
```

to change the caption's margins.

[image: a]

This is the complete code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{sidenotes} %% To typeset the rich content in the margin. It also loads caption package.

%% ************************************************* added
\newlength{\xtramargin}
\setlength{\xtramargin}{\dimexpr \marginparsep +\marginparwidth}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{widefigure}{format=plain,font=normalsize,labelfont=bf,textfont=up,
    labelsep=period, margin={0cm,-\xtramargin},oneside }
%% ************************************************

\begin{document}    
    
    \begin{figure*}[!t]
        \centering
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image}}
        \caption{(a) The electric field vector of linearly polarised monochromatic light,
            travelling along $z$, at a given instant of time. The 
            entire pattern moves past any given plane, say $z=0$; so the time
            variation would be the same curve read in reverse, with the part at
            positive $z$ arriving earlier. The magnetic field B is shown
            only at one plane, $z=0$, but is equal to the electric field (in
            cgs units!) but along $y$.}
    \end{figure*}
    
    xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx 
    
    \marginpar{xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx}
    
    
    \newpage
    
    \begin{figure*}[!t]
        \centering
        \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.98\linewidth]{example-image}}
        \caption{(a) The electric field vector of linearly polarised monochromatic light,
            travelling along $z$, at a given instant of time. The 
            entire pattern moves past any given plane, say $z=0$; so the time
            variation would be the same curve read in reverse, with the part at
            positive $z$ arriving earlier. The magnetic field B is shown
            only at one plane, $z=0$, but is equal to the electric field (in
            cgs units!) but along $y$.}
    \end{figure*}
    
    
    xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx 
    
    \marginpar{xxx x x xx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx zx}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I also reported the issue to Caption package author Axel Sommerfeldt. He has a workaround for the issue and updated the package hosted in Gitlab. He said that by next week the update may be available in CTAN.